# Redirect from root to subfolders and hiding subfolders permanently

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect subfolders to the main domain hiding the subfolders permanently.

So, `www.domain.com` should go to the files located in `www.domain.com/v2/wordpress` but permanently hiding the `v2/wordpress/`

Below is the code in the .htaccess I am using currently, and it works if you go to `www.domain.com` but on any other page, it is revealing the full path `www.domain.com/v2/wordpress/some-page.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/wordpress/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ v2/wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Is there a way to permanently hide the v2/wordpress/ on all urls?

Answer (score 0):

Actually did it trough wordpress settings http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory